# MGS Ground Zeroes: Getting 100% Completion

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

How do you achieve 100% completion in Metal Gear Solid: Ground Zeroes?

I believe you need to complete every level to S-Rank, on both Normal and Hard, but I've done that for certain levels (such as Deja Vu) and I still don't have full Completion Ratios for them (in that instance I have 16/17).

I've read that you need to complete any Trials above ones marked "???", but I don't have any of those for Deja Vu.

There's a lot of speculation online, but I'd like to know *exactly* what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get 100% on the PS4. What I remember doing was:

**Passing every mission on Normal** -> This Unlocks the Hard difficulty.

**I grabbed every XOF badge.**

**I grabbed all the Cassette Tapes.**

I passed every mission on Hard -> **And what I did was play every mission on Hard twice**. **So in every mission I get an S-Rank (**Both in Medium and Hard** this is required to get 100%)**. And then I **play them again** to set a score for the time-trials etc.. (If you have gotten an S-Rank before just chill out a little bit and have fun - try new things :D)

Then I remember being stuck at 90 something % so I googled and I needed to at least do one challenge in the Ground Zeroes Mission. For me it was Marking All Enemies (but I guess you can choose whichever one you think is easier). I think that Marking All Enemies is kind of fun and easy so it's an easy way of getting the challenge done. I did it on Medium in my PS4 playthrough(I have 100% in the PS4) and currently on my PC playthrough(I have 90% on my PC) I did it on Hard.

It doesn't really matter the difficulty. Just yesterday I played on mission again on medium and another on Hard (missions I had only completed once) and the percentage went up and more trials were filled.

I consulted this guide to achieve all this (Check it out if you want):

[Ground Zeroes 100% Guide](http://mgsforums.com/topic/7671194/1/)

Hope I Helped!